# Отслеживаем мышь и клавиатуру

Tags: c#

Задача такая: если пользователь в течении пяти минут не трогал клавиатуру и мышь (не нажимал кнопки и не двигал курсором) запускать приложение. Причем это касается и удаленных сеансов. Понимаю что это возможно решается через глобальных хук, но есть какие нибудь более простые способы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону планировщика задач. Может так будет проще всего.
[image: Тригер]
[image: Условие]

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы не поставить на сервере TimeOut в 5 минут, а затем вот

[этим](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132620/how-do-you-retrieve-a-list-of-logged-in-connected-users-in-net) кодом не проверять время от времени сессии:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace EnumerateRDUsers
{
  class Program
  {
    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr WTSOpenServer([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String pServerName);

    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
    static extern void WTSCloseServer(IntPtr hServer);

    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
    static extern Int32 WTSEnumerateSessions(
        IntPtr hServer,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] Int32 Reserved,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] Int32 Version,
        ref IntPtr ppSessionInfo,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] ref Int32 pCount);

    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
    static extern void WTSFreeMemory(IntPtr pMemory);

    [DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll")]
    static extern bool WTSQuerySessionInformation(
        System.IntPtr hServer, int sessionId, WTS_INFO_CLASS wtsInfoClass, out System.IntPtr ppBuffer, out uint pBytesReturned);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct WTS_SESSION_INFO
    {
      public Int32 SessionID;

      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
      public String pWinStationName;

      public WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS State;
    }

    public enum WTS_INFO_CLASS
    {
      WTSInitialProgram,
      WTSApplicationName,
      WTSWorkingDirectory,
      WTSOEMId,
      WTSSessionId,
      WTSUserName,
      WTSWinStationName,
      WTSDomainName,
      WTSConnectState,
      WTSClientBuildNumber,
      WTSClientName,
      WTSClientDirectory,
      WTSClientProductId,
      WTSClientHardwareId,
      WTSClientAddress,
      WTSClientDisplay,
      WTSClientProtocolType
    }
    public enum WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS
    {
      WTSActive,
      WTSConnected,
      WTSConnectQuery,
      WTSShadow,
      WTSDisconnected,
      WTSIdle,
      WTSListen,
      WTSReset,
      WTSDown,
      WTSInit
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      ListUsers("<INSERT SERVERNAME HERE>");
    }

    public static IntPtr OpenServer(String Name)
    {
      IntPtr server = WTSOpenServer(Name);
      return server;
    }
    public static void CloseServer(IntPtr ServerHandle)
    {
      WTSCloseServer(ServerHandle);
    }
    public static void ListUsers(String ServerName)
    {
      IntPtr serverHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
      List<String> resultList = new List<string>();
      serverHandle = OpenServer(ServerName);

      try
      {
        IntPtr SessionInfoPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr userPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr domainPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        Int32 sessionCount = 0;
        Int32 retVal = WTSEnumerateSessions(serverHandle, 0, 1, ref SessionInfoPtr, ref sessionCount);
        Int32 dataSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
        IntPtr currentSession = SessionInfoPtr;
        uint bytes = 0;

        if (retVal != 0)
        {
          for (int i = 0; i < sessionCount; i++)
          {
            WTS_SESSION_INFO si = (WTS_SESSION_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure((System.IntPtr)currentSession, typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
            currentSession += dataSize;

            WTSQuerySessionInformation(serverHandle, si.SessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSUserName, out userPtr, out bytes);
            WTSQuerySessionInformation(serverHandle, si.SessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSDomainName, out domainPtr, out bytes);

            Console.WriteLine("Domain and User: " + Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(domainPtr) + "\\" + Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(userPtr));

            WTSFreeMemory(userPtr); 
            WTSFreeMemory(domainPtr);
          }

          WTSFreeMemory(SessionInfoPtr);
        }
      }
      finally
      {
        CloseServer(serverHandle);
      }

    }

  }
}
```

В итоге, если установлен TimeOut в 5 минут, то сессия должна перейти в Idle.

Comment: не работает, блокирую сессии retVal как был нулем, так им и остается

Comment: @polsok Returns zero if this function fails. If this function succeeds, a nonzero value is returned. Вызови  GetLastError, что бы увидеть ошибку.